# BrowseRouter Module Exporting

Tags: reactjs

Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=30503ddf' does not provide an export named 'BrowseRouter'

Exporting the module is not done it shows the error which stops the development server

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.